# Wagtail RichTextField not showing in Django ModelForm

Tags: django, wagtail

My problem is that the RichTextField is the only field not displayed in the form.

I have a Model:

```
class RealestateObject(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        verbose_name=_('Object Title'),
    )

    summary = RichTextField(
        verbose_name=_('Summary'),
        blank=True, null=True,
    )

    description = models.TextField(
        verbose_name=_('Description'),
        blank=True, null=True,
)
```

And a form:

```
class RealestateObjectForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = TestRealestateObject
    fields = ('title',
              'summary',
              'description'
              )
```

and my template:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Insert</button>
</form>
```

the title and description field are displayed in the form, the summary not.
Is there a solution for this and/or a work around? I can't use the Wagtail Form Builder. 
It also would be great if I could use the richtext editor.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`RichTextField` depends on some additional Javascript and CSS which is defined through Django [form media](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/media/). You need to add the following to your template (preferably within the HTML `<head>` section):

```
{{ form.media.js }}
{{ form.media.css }}
```

Bear in mind that `RichTextField` is primarily designed for use within the Wagtail admin interface, and some of its functionality (especially the popup link/image choosers) may well depend on other JS/CSS from there - disabling these features through [the `features` argument](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5.1/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html#limiting-features-in-a-rich-text-field) is one option for dealing with that.

Comment: Thanks. That works. I only had to add the vendor.js and initialize wagtailConfig .